# ES212 USB microphone auto gain?

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10 on amd64. I've got this USB microphone that identifies in `dmesg` as:

```
[367608.589843] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b3f, idProduct=0212, bcdDevice= 1.00
[367608.589848] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[367608.589851] usb 1-1: Product: ES212 USB Microphone
[367608.589854] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MUSIC-BOOST
[367608.589856] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: ES-212
[367608.597441] input: MUSIC-BOOST ES212 USB Microphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.3/0003:1B3F:0212.0014/input/input90
[367608.654872] hid-generic 0003:1B3F:0212.0014: input,hidraw1: USB HID v2.01 Device [MUSIC-BOOST ES212 USB Microphone] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input3
```

PulseAudio seems to pick it up fine and it shows up as an input device under Settings > Sound.

However, if I try to record audio (using gnome-sound-recorder), it's incredibly quiet. (Note that the microphone has a volume dial but it's cranked all the way up already.)

Now, if I try to use the device on Windows, it's also really quiet by default *but* if I click through to the advanced device properties, there's an [AGC (auto gain control) checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlQLu.png) under "Custom". If I enable that, I get pretty decent recording quality out of it.

Based on the [device properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXX9j.png), Windows didn't install a proprietary driver, as it's using "Generic USB Audio". Hence, it looks as though the device is communicating to Windows that AGC is available, and enabling the checkbox toggles it on properly.

I was hoping PulseAudio (or some other component) would receive this same communication on the AGC feature somehow, and that I would be able to turn it on just like on Windows - perhaps by editing a config file? I don't know where to look though.

By the way, I'm aware that the audio system also has an AGC implementation, but the audio is still really quiet if I max out the microphone's input volume. Hence, I think this needs to be solved at the device level.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever found a solution of how to get AGC on Linux?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

The PulseAudio Volume Utility (`pavucontrol`) might give you what you're looking for ... to a point. I use this with my microphones:

[image: Pulse Audio Volume Utility]

If you do not already have it installed, you can do so like this:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Once installed, you can open the application like any other.

Hope this gets you closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have mentioned that after reading other answers, I'd tried that already. It does indeed allow me to push the volume beyond 0 dB, but even at the max of 153%, it's still really quiet. The VU meter of my laptop's internal mic goes way further than the external one's. Also, this is not adaptive like on Windows, but it might be a good start if I could ramp the level up far enough.